# Extract Header and Footer content from a .doc file using python textract or alternative lib

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract page content along with header and footer content. I tried using textract lib. for .docx it's good. But it's not the same for .doc

I tried checking other libraries but none of it worked for me.

Below I have snippet for .docx

```
import textract
def convert_to_txt(filename):
    try:
        my_text = textract.process(filename, encoding='ascii')
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "Couldn't able to open the file: {}".format(filename)
        raise RuntimeError(msg)
    return my_text
```

Comment: textract is the combination of `python-docx` for .docx files and [more](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I specifically looking for a lib. supports reading .doc file header and footer text.

Comment: Above code works for docx header, footer, and page content as well. The same code works for page content of .doc but it's not fetching header and footer content of .doc file. I am looking for alternatives lib. to read header and footer or solution in textract lib.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better solution to this problem :

**Method Used to extract**

using MS XML Word document

just zip the word document using zip module, It will give you access to xml format of word document, then you can use simple xml node extraction for text.

Following is the working code that extracts **Header**, **Footer**, **Text Data** from a docx file.

```
try:
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import XML
except ImportError:
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
import zipfile    
WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
PARA = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'


def get_docx_text(path):
    """
    Take the path of a docx file as argument, return the text in unicode.
    """
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    contentToRead = ["header2.xml", "document.xml", "footer2.xml"]
    paragraphs = []

    for xmlfile in contentToRead:
        xml_content = document.read('word/{}'.format(xmlfile))
        tree = XML(xml_content)
        for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
            texts = [node.text
                     for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
                     if node.text]
            if texts:
                textData = ''.join(texts)
                if xmlfile == "footer2.xml":
                    extractedTxt = "Footer : " + textData
                elif xmlfile == "header2.xml":
                    extractedTxt = "Header : " + textData
                else:
                    extractedTxt = textData

                paragraphs.append(extractedTxt)
    document.close()
    return '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)


print(get_docx_text("E:\\path_to.docx"))
```

Comment: Thanks @toheedniaz, Not all the files working .docx. None of the .doc working for me. The .doc file doesn't contains `["header2.xml", "document.xml", "footer2.xml"]` none of them